# Why does urlopen read() produce unexpected behavior

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

This is probably a naive question because I'm a python beginner so here goes...

This works...

```
import urllib.request
web=urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/RTBM/LMP_By_SETTLEMENT_LOC/2015/05/05/')
filelist=web.read().decode('utf-8').split('\r\n')
```

but this doesn't

```
filelist=urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/RTBM/LMP_By_SETTLEMENT_LOC/2015/05/05/').read().decode('utf-8').split('\r\n')`
```

specifically, it just either hangs and I have to cancel the command or it returns a list where item 0 is an empty string

Another bit of strange behavior occurs if I do

```
web=urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://pubftp.spp.org/Markets/RTBM/LMP_By_SETTLEMENT_LOC/2015/05/05/')
web.read() #dumps all the contents as expected
web.read() #now just displays b''
```

I'm guessing these two bits of behavior are related and that `read()` changes the underlying object for some reason.

Obviously it's easy enough to just use the former syntax but I'm sure this gotcha will come back to bite me with something else in the future if I don't know what is really going on.

Comment: You can read only once I guess

Comment: @thefourtheye, agreed. calling `read` moves the "file position" value to the end of the file, so trying to read again only returns the empty string. But that only seems to explain his "another bit of strange behavior", and not his first problem.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with already-open web connections hogging system resources, which makes subsequent requests hang. How are you running these code snippets? Does the behavior still persist if you close your IDE/session/whatever in between testing the first snippet and the second one?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think its a problem of resources.  I've got 32gb of ram and while the list is long for a person to look at, it is only a small amount of data.  I'm running these examples directly in console and it persists even on a fresh console.